# std::bind and rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

Let's consider the following piece of code:

```
class Widget{
};

int main(){
Widget w;
auto lambda = bind([](Widget&& ref){ return; }, std::move(w));

return 0;
}
```

and it triggers error

```
no match for call to ‘(std::_Bind<main()::<lambda(Widget&&)>(Widget)>) ()’
     lambda();
```

And my question is: Why the error has appeared? After all, I do an explicit cast to rvalue reference – I mean `std::move(w)` and I take argument by rvalue reference – I mean `Widget&& ref`.

What's up?

Moreover the the below code works, what makes me worried the more:

```
class Widget{
};

int main(){
Widget w;
auto lambda = bind([](Widget& ref){ return; }, std::move(w));

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It might become clearer if you write down what `std::bind` schematically does.

```
// C++14, you'll have to write a lot of boilerplate code for C++11
template <typename FuncT, typename ArgT>
auto
bind(FuncT&& func, ArgT&& arg)
{
  return
    [
      f = std::forward<FuncT>(func),
      a = std::forward<ArgT>(arg)
    ]() mutable { return f(a); };  // NB: a is an lvalue here
}
```

Since you can call the function object `std::bind` gives you multiple times, it cannot “use up” the captured argument so it will be passed as an lvalue reference. The fact that you pass `bind` itself an rvalue only means that there is no copy made on the line where `a` is initialized.

If you try to compile your example with the schematic `bind` shown above, you'll also get a more helpful error message from your compiler.

```
main.cxx: In instantiation of ‘bind(FuncT&&, ArgT&&)::<lambda()> mutable [with FuncT = main()::<lambda(Widget&&)>; ArgT = Widget]’:
main.cxx:10:33:   required from ‘struct bind(FuncT&&, ArgT&&) [with FuncT = main()::<lambda(Widget&&)>; ArgT = Widget]::<lambda()>’
main.cxx:11:31:   required from ‘auto bind(FuncT&&, ArgT&&) [with FuncT = main()::<lambda(Widget&&)>; ArgT = Widget]’
main.cxx:18:59:   required from here
main.cxx:11:26: error: no match for call to ‘(main()::<lambda(Widget&&)>) (Widget&)’
    ]() mutable { return f(a); };  // NB: a is an lvalue here
                          ^
main.cxx:11:26: note: candidate: void (*)(Widget&&) <conversion>
main.cxx:11:26: note:   conversion of argument 2 would be ill-formed:
main.cxx:11:26: error: cannot bind ‘Widget’ lvalue to ‘Widget&&’
main.cxx:18:33: note: candidate: main()::<lambda(Widget&&)> <near match>
   auto lambda = bind([](Widget&&){ return; }, std::move(w));
                                 ^
main.cxx:18:33: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
main.cxx:11:26: error: cannot bind ‘Widget’ lvalue to ‘Widget&&’
    ]() mutable { return f(a); };  // NB: a is an lvalue here
```

Answer (score 3):

To make it work you need to write it like this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class Widget{};

int main()
{
    Widget a;
    auto lf = [](Widget&& par){ };

    auto f = std::bind
    (
        lf,
        std::bind
        (
            std::move<Widget&>, a
        )
    );
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

My compiler is `gcc version 4.9.2 20141101 (Red Hat 4.9.2-1) (GCC)`

Comment: How did you figure out that this example doesn't work? I successfully compiled it with my compiler. What compiler do you use?

Comment: Sorry, I was confused with the naming of my procedures, GCC didn't tell me that there were two function to call.

Comment: It won't work if `Widget` has an explicit move ctor. My compiler is GNU C++ 8.3.0.