# Perfectly transform a 2-tuple into a pair

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17, template-meta-programming, perfect-forwarding

I want an utility to transform a `std::tuple<T,U>` to `std::pair<T,U>`, while leaving a `std::tuple<T, U, V, W...>` unchanged.

Furthermore, I want this utility to

- be a function object, not a function, so that I can pass it around as I like;
- enforce that it's input must be a `std::tuple`;
- taking advantage of move semantics whenever it is possible to do so and it makes sense.

**The last point is the difficult part, for me, and it's the reason I'm asking this question.**

---

I know that tuples can store values as well as references (lvalue references as well as rvalue references), so imagine that the sought function, if fed with an rvalue 2-tuple, it could steal resources from the non-reference components, but should leave intact the reference component.

For instance given

```
A a;
B b;
std::tuple<A, B&> t{a,b};
```

where I know `a` is copied in the tuple, while `b` is not, I think that doing

```cpp
auto p{to_pair(t)};
```

should result in a `std::pair<A, B&>` which holds another copy of `a` and a reference to the only `b` that exists so far.

On the other hand, doing

```cpp
B b;
auto p{to_pair(std::tuple<A, B&>{A{},b})};
```

should result again in a `std::pair<A, B&>`, but this would hold the very `A{}` of which no copy should ever be made; and it would hold a reference to `b` anyway.

---

The scenario described above is already enough for me to be in doubt about what to do, let alone thinking of other combinations of `&`/`const&`/`&&`.

Some time ago I had a hard time [answering a question about `std::tuple`s and perfect forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66300832/5825294), but I can never say I've understood them fully.

Comment: You have to at least **move** the `A{}` in the latter use case, since it's already there in the `tuple`.  Is that OK?

Comment: @DavisHerring, if you mean that it's moved from the temporary tuple to the non-temporary pair instead of being constructed in place in the pair, that's totally fine. And I suspect that's the most I can do without falling in non-sensical code? Or not?

Comment: Wouldn't `std::make_from_tuple` do almost all of the work here for you, then?

Comment: I didn't know of that function. Probably it'll do. I'll check it soon.

Comment: @DavisHerring, you mean something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/MzWzjve1W)?

Comment: That looks reasonable; you might or might not be able to simplify it with some `if constexpr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<class...Fs>
struct overloaded : Fs... {
  using Fs::operator()...;
};
template<class...Fs>
overloaded(Fs&&...)->overloaded<std::decay_t<Fs>...>;

auto move_tuples = []<class...Ts>(std::tuple<Ts...> x){return std::move(x);};
auto to_pair = []<class A, class B>(std::tuple<A, B> x){
  return std::pair<A,B>( std::get<0>(std::move(x)), std::get<1>(std::move(x)) );
};
auto your_function = overloaded{move_tuples, to_pair};
```

I think that is what you want.

I take the arguments by value, then move them to the return value.  If they are values, the result is that the contained values are moved.  If they are references, they aren't, the references are just propagated.

The `get<N>` "does the right thing" when passed an rvalue tuple.  If returns an rvalue from a value.

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) you'll have to replace the lambdas with manual structs.

Or write two normal overloads, and

```
auto obj=[](auto&&x)->decltype(normal_func(decltype(x)(x))){return decltype(x)(x);};
```

to turn the overloaded function call `normal_func` into a single function object.

Comment: Some feedback: 1. template parameter lists are C++20, not C++17, but I guess hand-written `struct`s solve the problem; 2. you could have saved a few lines with [`boost::hana::overload`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-functional.html#ga83e71bae315e299f9f5f9de77b012139), and from your profile I think you know of Hana well, so I'm wondering if you _intentionally_ didn't use that for some performance or other reason; [3. this solution breaks down as soon as I start passing rvalue references template arguments to `std::tuple`](https://godbolt.org/z/zxd5Pjaje).

Comment: Oh, as regards the 3rd point in the previous comment, I don't actually have an idea of why I would do that, but my reasoning is: I am allowed to write `std::tuple<int, int&&> t{1,1};`, and the function I seek would allow doing `auto p = that_func(t);` which would result in `p` being just the pair version of the 2-tuple; I wouldn't want to use `t` anymore, so it can end up being invalid, if necessary.

Comment: @enlico Made the pair store references.  I saw no need to add an external library dependency to save 6 lines.

Comment: The question wasn't tagged `[boost]` so a boost solution wasn't asked for.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont, fair enough about Hana (I thought there might me some non StackOverflow-specific reason that you avoided it). As regards rvalue refefences in the tuple, I still see [the same error](https://godbolt.org/z/3Gz9s3nT9). I see this is no different from defining `struct A { int&& i; };` and then attempting `A a{1}; A b{a};`.

Comment: @enlico you have to move the tuple in.  It contains an rvalue reference, duplicating that without moving from is unsafe.

Comment: I think I need to ask another question to clarify some misunderstanding I have about this topic. But as regards the present question, this means that at the call site have to inspect the types in the tuple to make the decision of whether `std::move` it or not when I pass it to `your_function`, which seems a bit cumbersome.

Comment: @enlico If you are keeping and using the source tuple *and* the destination, some types cannot be sensibly supported without complex semantics.  If you are not, then always move.  Values stored will be moved to the return value, references forwarded in that case.